# gulp-jshint task is taking over 5 minutes to complete

Tags: build, gulp, jshint, gulp-jshint

I'm working with gulp and am fairly new, my gulp jshint task is as follow:

```
 gulp.task('jshint', ()=>{
  return gulp.src([`${root}/**/*.js`])
  .pipe(jshint('.jshintrc'))
  .pipe(jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'))
  .pipe(jshint.reporter('gulp-jshint-html-reporter', { filename: 'jshint-output.html' }))
  .pipe(jshint.reporter('fail'));
});
```

The task is taking 5mins every time I run my build. Is there anyway to speed this up?

$root is src, it is not running through node_modules.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, there were some lib files being picked up that shouldn't have and as they were huge they caused jshint to take longer. *flips desk*